# Linq Help- Where Is Not in where clause

Tags: vb.net, linq

I am having this issue with my Linq Query.  I am new to Linq. I've searched the net and I do not have a solution to this.

Essentially I want the query to run but only return results that don't have  "5" in one of the fields (I didn't design this program originally)

This is what I have that gives me an error

```
Dim distinctRow = (From dr In (From _
                               row In _AcademicChoices.AsEnumerable() _
                               Select New With {.ID = row("AC_Academic_Choice_ID"), .Marketing = row("AC_Marketing_Desc"), .Program = row("AC_Program_Code"), .Track = row("AC_Track"), .DisplayRestrictedOn = row("DisplayRestrictedOn")} _
                             ) _
                   Where !dr.DisplayRestrictedOn.ToString().Contains("5")
                   Select dr.ID, dr.Marketing, dr.Program, dr.DisplayRestrictedOn, dr.Track Distinct)
```

The error lies in the Where statement.  I get an error that says "Leading '.' or '!' can only appear inside a 'With' statement."

Any assistance on how to proceed would be appreciated.

Comment: You could always use `Where (-1 < dr.DisplayRestrictedOn.ToString().IndexOf("5"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`!dr.DisplayRestrictedOn.ToString().Contains("5")` is not a valid expression in that context.  The `!` does not represent a logical `Not` in VB as it does in C# (or other similar languages).

That line should be:

```vb
Where Not dr.DisplayRestrictedOn.ToString().Contains("5")
```